# Is there any way to get name of the first, the second, the third table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection, websecurity

I'm gathering information about the database by executing time-based SQL injection attacks (in lab environment). I discovered the current database user and the current database name. But now I don't know the way to get names of the first, the second, the third [,...] tables in that current database. Is there any way can help solve the problem?

I'm working with PostgreSQL, but if you know any way in another DBMS, please tell me, I'm so so grateful!

Answer (score 0):

To list all tables in the current database, you can run the `\dt` command in psql.